# Safely renaming remote origin branch

Tags: git, git-branch

My local branch is mapped to a remote one:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/release/old_branch:refs/remotes/origin/release/old_branch
```

I'd like to rename both local and remote `old_branch` into `new_branch`. [w3docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-rename-git-local-and-remote-branches.html) recommends this:

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally    
git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch    
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote
```

However, there are a couple other developers who are also working on the same remote `old_branch` as I do. Is the above recommendation safe in collaborative environment? If their `.git/config` has lines similar to mine above, wouldn't this sequence confuse their fetch references?

Comment: why not just create new branch from old, public it, and work with this new one?

Comment: @VelikiiNehochuha, makes sense: if somebody keeps using old_branch and the branches diverge I'll just merge the changes to new_branch. Thanks, will do.

Comment: Create new (via `git push -u origin new_branch`) before deleting old. In some cases this doesn't matter; in other cases, where it does matter, it makes the "create new" operation significantly more efficient. You might wonder when (and why) it is more efficient: the answer is, if deleting the old name triggers a server side `git gc` that throws out commits reachable from the old name, your subsequent push to create the new name must re-send all the commits the `git gc` just threw away. If you create first, all the commits are retained.

Answer (score 0):

Given your stated goal to rename the branch on local and remote - taking that to mean that locally and on the remote there should, at the end, be a`new_branch` pointing to where `old_branch` previously pointed, and there should no longer be an `old_branch` - then the procedure you listed is as good as any.

This is because when another developer fetch's, their repo won't "know" / be affected by what commands were used to get to that end state.  They will simply see that `old_branch` is gone and that there is a new branch called `new_branch`.

Now, such repos won't automatically delete their `origin/old_branch` ref; by default they'll keep it where it is unless/until using `fetch` with the `--prune` option.  That also means they could potentially re-push it (without ever realizing you'd deleted it).

In other words, you won't confuse `git`, but you *could* confuse teammates - so you need to communicate with the team to make sure people know what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend creating a `new_branch` and informing the other developers to use the new branch (and deleting the `old_branch`).

In case a developer keeps using the old branch you can just merge their commits to the `new_branch` until he switches to the `new_branch`.